# LINQ methods executing sequence

Tags: c#, .net, linq, clr

I am reading a book about C# in advanced level. And, now I am reading this part:

*Behind-the-scenes operation of the Linq query methods that implement delegate-based syntax.*

So far, I have read about `Where`, `Select`, `Skip`, `SkipWhile`, `Take`, `TakeWhile` methods.
And, I know about *Defferred* and *Immediate* execution and `Iterator`s which is returned by some of these methods.

> Deferred execution is a pattern of the execution model by which the
>   CLR ensures a value will be extracted only when it is required from
>   the IEnumerable-based information source. When any Linq operator
>   uses the deferred execution, the CLR encapsulates the related
>   information, such as the original sequence, predicate, or selector (if
>   any), into an iterator, which will be used when the information is
>   extracted from the original sequence using ToListmethod or
>   ForEachmethod or manually using the underlying GetEnumeratorand
>   MoveNextmethods in C#.

Now let's take these two examples:

```
IList<int> series = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

// First example
series.Where(x => x > 0).TakeWhile(x => x > 0).ToList();

// Second example
series.Where(x => x > 0).Take(4).ToList();
```

When I am putting breakpoints and debugging these two statements, I can see one difference.

`TakeWhile()` method executing  when an item is met the condition in `Where` statement. But, this is not the case with `Take` method.

**First statement:**

[image]
[image]

**Second statement:**

[image]
[image]

Could you explain me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *entirely* clear what you mean, but if you're asking why you hit a breakpoint in the lambda expression in `TakeWhile`, but you don't hit one within `Take`, it's just that `Take` doesn't accept a delegate at all - it just accepts a number. There's no user-defined code to execute while it's finding a value to return, so there's no breakpoint to hit.

In your example with `TakeWhile`, you've got two lambda expressions - one for `Where` and one for `TakeWhile`. So you can break into *either* of those lambda expressions.

It's important to understand that the `Where` and `TakeWhile` methods themselves are only called *once* - but the sequences they return evaluate the delegate passed to them for each value they encounter.

You might want to look at my [Edulinq blog series](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/) for more details about the innards of LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have explained me what I need. And from this, I got one result. One of the inputs in some LINQ methods is the type of the `MulticastDelegate`. And therefore CLR adds all methods In statement to this delegate. And this delegate executes all methods sequentally for each item in the List. Am I true?
(I have tried to explain what I got, and I want to be sure that I got it right or not)

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: Where have you seen `MulticastDelegate` in the LINQ signatures? I don't remember ever seeing this. I'm not sure what you mean by "CLR adds all methods in statement to this delegate". It sounds like you should ask this in more detail, with sample code, in a new question.

Comment: Ok, let me explain my question in detail. Let's take first example in my question.
I have used two anonymous functions there. One for `Where` and the other for `TakeWhile` method. As i know, the C# compiler constructs a new method using the anonymous method in the compile time. And CLR will instantiate an instance of `MulticastDelegate` using this method as a predicate to the methods. And CLR is just executing all methods which is referenced by this delegate for each item in the sequence. 
Am I true?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: No, the compiler creates a new instance of `Func<string, bool>` or whatever. `MulticastDelegate` is an abstract class. It's not clear what you mean by "all the methods" here - there's only one method. But your question is really nothing to do with LINQ, so if this isn't enough detail, please ask a new question as I mentioned before.

Comment: Ok, actually I want to know what LINQ is compiled to? Let me read your blog. And after that, I will ask my question if I have any. Thanks, again.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again. But, I have read your blog and the book which I was reading again. Now, I don't have any question. But, I want to get your thoughts about one thing. In my book, the author keeps saying `MulticastDelegate` instead of `Func<...>` and he says that:
`The System.Func<TSource,TResult>is derived from the MulticastDelegate. So, The CLR creates a MulticastDelegate instance using the method <Main>b__1.`
So, is this sentecne wrong about creating a MulticastDelegate instance?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: Well it depends on exactly what you mean by "a MulticastDelegate instance". An instance of `Func<Foo,Bar>` *is* an instance of `MulticastDelegate` due to inheritance, but I wouldn't use that term when creating an instance - I'd talk about the concrete actual type being created. (I wouldn't say "The CLR creates a System.Object instance" for example - that's just as true, for the same reason.)

Comment: I am totally agree with you. This sentence of the author really confused me. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the condition in `TakeWhile` will need to be evaluated for each item, just like `Where`, so it will call each of them for each item.

`Take(4)` does not need to be evaluated per item, only the `Where` does, so in the second one, only the `Where` condition will be evaluated each time, (probably four times).